Jmeter in cli mode
I need to check the response in jmeter, I had assertion in GUI
enter image description here
But I run the test in cli mode and when I get the answer, I only see the status code, but I need to check a specific answer
enter image description here
how I can check response of my test?
how I can check response of my test? maybe I need another report

Given you have true value in success column in the .jtl results file it means that your assertion has passed, otherwise your Sampler would fail.
Assertion failure messages can be seen for example in HTML Reporting Dashboard. Also it will be seen in failureMessage column in the .jtl results file.
In order to generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard you can add the next command-line arguments:
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard

once test execution is finished open index.html file using your favourite browser.
More information:

Generating Reports
JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips

